# How can I get DynamoDbContext to throw an exception on Save if an item hash key already exists

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating a new item in DynamoDB and I want it to throw an exception if the hash key already exists.  I want this, because I don't want to have to query for an item before the insert for performance reasons, as it is extremely unlikely that my key will collide.  but if it does i want to retry with a new key.  Currently when I call Save via the object level api, it just updates the record.

```
public class DynamoService
{
    private readonly IDynamoDBContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IAmazonDynamoDB _dynamoClient;

    public DynamoService(IAmazonDynamoDB dynamoClient, IDynamoDBContext dbContext )
    {
        _dynamoClient = dynamoClient;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual async Task Save<T>(T item) where T : new()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveAsync(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a conditional expression using `attribute_not_exists` to your PutItem request.

See the section "Preventing Overwrites of an Existing Item" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

The conditional expression will cause a `ConditionalCheckFailedException` if the item already exists, which you can catch and then do your retry logic

Comment: This implies that you have to NOT use the .NET Object Persistence model that OP is using (as evident by the SaveAsync call against the context). Is there a way to actually do this using the context?

Comment: @IsolatedThinker I think I have found a way to do this using the .NET Object Persistence model. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70623880/659254

Comment: It's really insane to me that this is not easier to do using the .NET Object Persistence model.

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible with the .NET Object Persistence model by using "Optimistic Locking" ([described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.VersionSupport.html))

Inside your class you have to mark one property for being used as a `VersionNumber`.

```cs
public class DynamoDbItem
{
   [DynamoDBHashKey]
   public string SomeId { get; set; }       
    
   // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.VersionSupport.html
   [DynamoDBVersion]
   public int? VersionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

During saving you need to specify that you want to perform a version check.

```cs
public virtual async Task Save<T>(T item) where T : new()
{
    await _dbContext.SaveAsync(item, new DynamoDBOperationConfig
            {
               SkipVersionCheck = false
            });
}
```

For creating the item (saving for the first time) set the `VersionNumber = null`. The item will be saved in DynamoDB with `VersionNumber = 0`. Then if you try to create an item with the same PrimaryKey (and SortKey) `VersionNumber = null` (from C#) will not match `VersionNumber = 0` (saved in DynamoDB) and `SaveAsync` will throw an exception.

Note: This only works if you specify `SkipVersionCheck = false` either as `DynamoDBOperationConfig` or as `DynamoDBContextConfig` on `_dbContext`.